# String parameter being divided because of '&' character on http post request

Tags: ios, swift, httpwebrequest

My string parameter is being divided because contain "&" and '=' character.  The only solutions I thought is replace these characters using stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString and do the opposite in my server but I think that can't be the best solution.

My parameter is an url: "[https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xft1/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/10407385_1036550749695345_6853981176259794158_n.jpg?oh=ab150587befc541e8e3419b2fa245333&oe=56985B8D&**gda**=1456547848_432c041c647a7b3fd01f0adb33183aab](https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xft1/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/10407385_1036550749695345_6853981176259794158_n.jpg?oh=ab150587befc541e8e3419b2fa245333&oe=56985B8D&__gda__=1456547848_432c041c647a7b3fd01f0adb33183aab)"

My code:

```
let url : NSString = "http://domain.com/test/service/signInUp?name=\(name)&email=\(email)&facebookID=\(facebookID)&photo=\(photo)"

            let urlStr : NSString = url.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
            let searchURL : NSURL = NSURL(string: urlStr as String)!

            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: searchURL)
            request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

            var response: NSURLResponse?

            var urlData: NSData?

            do {
                urlData = try NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response)
```

Comment: You simply need to use `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` on  `facebookID` *before* you put it into `url` then encode `urlStr` as you are now

Comment: You mean on `photo`? I tried and had no success.

Comment: yes, photo, sorry I was confused as to which parameter was the URL.  The other question I would have is do you actually *need* the query string after the .jpg ?

Comment: Yes, its is a user's photo url from facebook api. I can't access the photo without the query string after .jpg.

Comment: Apparently that method doesn't encode & - you can use the Core Foundation class to do it - http://cybersam.com/ios-dev/proper-url-percent-encoding-in-ios

Comment: Actually it turns out that that is deprecated in iOS 9.  The replacement is `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you include a URL in your query string, the query string in your included URL parameter will just be seen as part of the outer URL's query string and so things get messed up (technical term).

The solution is to percent encode the URL parameter before you put it into the URL but you can't use `stringByAddingPercentEncoding` because this function doesn't encode the & characters that are causing you the problem.

You can use`stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters()`

```
let encodedPhone = photo.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.alphanumericCharacterSet());

let url : NSString = "http://domain.com/test/service/signInUp?name=\(name)&email=\(email)&facebookID=\(facebookID)&photo=\(encodedPhoto!)"
```

You may need to percent decode this parameter on your server if it doesn't do this for you automatically

Comment: Encoded, but still divided in more than one parameter.

Comment: To be honest this would probably work better using a POST method rather than a GET method